# In map , whether the tr operator will affect the original array?

Tags: perl

I wrote the code like this,

```
    my (@Last,@Input);
@Input=qw(This is FOR Testing);
map{ tr/A-Z/a-z/;tr/a-z//cd;push @Last,$_;} @Input;
print "Original array ==>@Input<===\n";
print "Modified array ==>@Last<===\n";
```

Once I executed the code, I got the output like this,

```
Original array ==>this is for testing<===
Modified array ==>this is for testing<===
```

Whether the tr operator will affect the original array?

Comment: Using a `push` inside a `map` in void context is distasteful. What choroba shows is much more idiomatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr///` is destructive by default.

To preserve the original string you should use the `/r` modifier.

From [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> If the `/r` (non-destructive) option is present, a new copy of the
>   string is made and its characters transliterated, and this copy is
>   returned no matter whether it was modified or not

Answer (score 1):

On older Perls where `/r` wasn't available (introduced in 5.14), the common idiom was

```
my @Input = qw( This is FOR Testing );
my @Output = map {
    my $s = $_;        # Break the aliasing.
    $s =~ tr/A-Z/a-z/;
    $s =~ tr/a-z//cd;
    $s
} @Input;
```